# Angular - *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

In my Angular project, I do not know why but *ngFor don't show me one tag:

without `*ngFor`

[image: without "*ngFor"]
[image: without "*ngFor"]

with `*ngFor`

[image: with *ngFor]
[image: with *ngFor]

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post code as images. I see you aren't binding any data to the `*ngFor` directive. You need to bind an array or collection to it. Like `*ngFor="let item of items"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This

`<li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>`

Comment: I've already tried  
        <a 
        href="#
        class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor ="let recipe of recipes">
        
        <div class="pull-left" >
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ name.recipe }}</h4>
          </div>
            </div>

Comment: Its not name.recipe  its will recipe.name

Comment: try using the loop on the div not in the a tag

Comment: provide a stackblitz example

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` acts as a loop, I can see you have not entered anything inside ngFor which makes it run 0 times

Enter some condition like `*ngFor ="let recipe of recipes"`

it will surely display for number of items in recipes

Comment: after putting the condition also you are not able to see anything??

Comment: I've already tried  
        <a 
        href="#
        class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor ="let recipe of recipes">
        
        <div class="pull-left" >
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ name.recipe }}</h4>
          </div>

Comment: it should be recipe.name, are you sure recipes has a list of values??

Comment: Sorry already put {{ recipe.name}} but first issue the problem remains...

Comment: are you sure recipes has a list of values??

Comment: // component.ts recipes: Recipe[] = [
  new Recipe('Recipe', 'It´s just a teste recipe', 
  'https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/85695489-a0c9-41b6-b926-f8b4d3620f5e.jpg' )
];

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve the issue.

Had a component inserted (app-recipe-item) that was overlay code.

Thanks all.